# Problem with a session variable affecting other session variables in PHP

Tags: php, variables, session

When I try to use `$_SESSION['pageNumbers']`, it disables other session variables holding values:

**With:**
[image]

[image]

If I comment out `$_SESSION['pageNumbers']`, the other session variables work fine
("sixdigitpass" and "Logout" button):

**Without:**
[image]
[image]

I have `session_start();` in the *header.php*, but I do not uderstand why it does not allow me to use `$_SESSION['pageNumbers']` without affecting other session.

Can anyone please help me?

**CODES**

To get limited rows per page:

```
public function fetchAllStudents()
{
    $outputPerPage = 20;
    $sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM students';
    $statement = $this->_dbHandle->prepare($sqlQuery);
    $statement->execute(); // execute the PDO statement
    $resultNumber =  $statement->rowCount();
    $_SESSION['pageNumbers'] = ceil($resultNumber/$outputPerPage); // ERROR DETECTED 
    if(!isset($_GET['page']))
    {
        $page = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $page = $_GET['page'];
    }
    $currentFirstOutput = ($page-1)*$outputPerPage;
    $sqlNewQuery = "SELECT * FROM students LIMIT " . $currentFirstOutput . ',' . $outputPerPage;
    $statementNew = $this->_dbHandle->prepare($sqlNewQuery); // prepare a PDO statement
    $statementNew->execute(); // execute the PDO statement
    $statementNew->rowCount();
    while ($row = $statementNew->fetch()) {
        $dataSet[] = new StudentData($row);

    }
        return $dataSet;
}
```

display pagination:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['pageNumbers']))
{
    for ($page = 1; $page <= $_SESSION['pageNumbers']; $page++)
    {
        echo '<a href="index.php?page=' . $page . '">' . $page . '</a> ';
    }
}
?>
```

Below there are snipets that are affected if I use `$_SESSION['pageNumbers']`

To show user name if logged in:

```
Welcome,  <?php if(isset($_SESSION['user_ID'])){
            echo explode(" ", $_SESSION['full_name'])[0];
        } else {
            echo " Guest";
        }?>
```

To change from "Login" to Logout" if logged in:

```
    <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['user_ID'])) : ?>
    <a class="bb text-decoration-none" href="../../login.php">Login</a>
    <?php else: ?>
    <a class="bb" href="../../Models/Core.php?exit=logout">Logout</a>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Please paste code, not screenshots.

Comment: Okay, I will do.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I have added the codes to the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please copy and paste you code directly into the post 
instead of linking to, or inserting an image of it. To learn more about formatting please read: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

After 3 hours of manual debugging I found the solution, apparently adding `session_start();` before the line:

```
session_start(); // solution :)
$_SESSION['pageNumbers'] = ceil($resultNumber/$outputPerPage); // ERROR FIXED
```

I never needed to use `session_start();` in any function. If anyone expert would kindly point out the reason for this, I would appreciate it.

Comment: See php's ```session_start()``` documentation. 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: When session_start() is called or when a session auto starts, PHP will call the open and read session save handlers. These will either be a built-in save handler provided by default or by PHP extensions (such as SQLite or Memcached); or can be custom handler as defined by session_set_save_handler(). The read callback will retrieve any existing session data (stored in a special serialized format) and will be unserialized and used to automatically populate the $_SESSION superglobal when the read callback returns the saved session data back to PHP session handling.

Comment: Since you never initialized the session, the existing session information was unavailable to your code.